# Inner Join - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

Gente, preciso da ajuda de alguém para entender o erro que está dando.
Tenho duas tabelas como mostra o código, e em uma das tabelas a coluna **"CodigoPlano"** está com informações.
Preciso colocar os códigos relacionados com os Beneficiários.
Porém está dando o erro:

> Syntax "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'FROM' "

```
    SELECT [SemPlano].[NomeBenefTitular] AS [BenfTitularS], 
            [ComPlano].[NomeBenefTitular] AS [BenfTitularC],
            [SemPlano].[NomeUsuario]      AS [NomeUsuarioS], 
            [ComPlano].[NomeUsuario]      AS [NomeUsuarioC],
            [SemPlano].[CodigoPlano] AS [CodPlanoS], 
            [ComPlano].[CodigoPlano] AS [CodPlanoC],
       FROM [TabelaUm]   AS [SemPlano]
 INNER JOIN [TabelaDois] AS [ComPlano] ON [BenfTitularS] = [BenfTitularC]
```

Comment: Utilizar o alias criado para os campos no INNER JOIN ocasiona erro, na minha resposta mostro como deveria ser feita a pesquisa de forma correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto seria:

```
SELECT 
    [SemPlano].[NomeBenefTitular] AS [BenfTitularS], 
    [ComPlano].[NomeBenefTitular] AS [BenfTitularC],
    [SemPlano].[NomeUsuario]      AS [NomeUsuarioS], 
    [ComPlano].[NomeUsuario]      AS [NomeUsuarioC],
    [SemPlano].[CodigoPlano] AS [CodPlanoS], 
    [ComPlano].[CodigoPlano] AS [CodPlanoC]
FROM 
    [TabelaUm] AS [SemPlano]
INNER JOIN 
    [TabelaDois] AS [ComPlano] ON [SemPlano].[NomeBenefTitular] = [ComPlano].[NomeBenefTitular]
```

Answer (score 7):

Você esqueceu de retirar a vírgula antes do `FROM`, nesta linha `[ComPlano].[CodigoPlano] AS [CodPlanoC]`

E conforme comentário do [Paulo R. F. Amorim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/104831/paulo-r-f-amorim) : Utilizar o alias criado para os campos no `INNER JOIN` ocasiona erro

```
   SELECT [SemPlano].[NomeBenefTitular] AS [BenfTitularS], 
            [ComPlano].[NomeBenefTitular] AS [BenfTitularC],
            [SemPlano].[NomeUsuario]      AS [NomeUsuarioS], 
            [ComPlano].[NomeUsuario]      AS [NomeUsuarioC],
            [SemPlano].[CodigoPlano] AS [CodPlanoS], 
            [ComPlano].[CodigoPlano] AS [CodPlanoC]
       FROM [TabelaUm]   AS [SemPlano]
INNER JOIN [TabelaDois] AS [ComPlano] ON [SemPlano].[NomeBenefTitular] = [ComPlano].[NomeBenefTitular]
```

Comment: Utilizar o alias criado para os campos no INNER JOIN ocasiona erro, na minha resposta mostro como deveria ser feita a pesquisa de forma correta

Comment: Não tinha me atentado a isto.. alterei minha resposta para que fique correta